# How can I use a list outside the class?

Tags: java

In Java, I have a class Team contains a list of teammate

```
public class Team{
     private List<Teammate> tm =new ArrayList<>();
     public List<Teammate> getPersons(){return tm;}
     public void addTeammate(String name){tm.add(new Teammate(name));}

//nested class
     public final static class Teammate{
     private String name;
     public String getName(){return this.name;}
     private Teammate(String name){this.name=name;}
     } 
}
```

After that I want to initialize a Team and add new Teammates to the Team, how can I do it elegant? Thanks!

Comment: It seems your code has solved your problem. You just need to new a `Team` and call `addTeammate` to add teammate. It that not enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple static constructor like this:

```
static Team createTeam(String... teamMates) {
    Team team = new Team();
    for (String teamMate: teamMates) {
        team.addTeammate(teamMate);
    }
    return team;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Team team = Team.createTeam("Tim", "Mike");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your design is fine.  I would probably make the following changes.

- make the nested class and constructor public so it can be referenced from other classes.
- overload the `addTeammate` method so you can add either a Teammate object or a String for a name.
- add the `toString` method to the nested class.

Here is an example.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import junk.Team.Teammate;
public class TeamDemo {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Team team = new Team();
        team.addTeammate(new Teammate("John"));
        team.addTeammate(new Teammate("Bob"));
        team.addTeammate(new Teammate("Sally"));
        team.addTeammate("Sue");   // adding by name only
        List<Teammate> tm = team.getPersons();
        for (Teammate t: tm) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
     }
}
class Team {
    private List<Teammate> tm = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public List<Teammate> getPersons() {
        return tm;
    }
    
    public void addTeammate(String name) {
        tm.add(new Teammate(name));
    }
    
    public void addTeammate (Teammate teammate) {
        tm.add(teammate);
    }
    
//nested class
    public final static class Teammate {
        private String name;
        
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
        
        public Teammate(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

When run it prints.

```
John
Bob
Sally
Sue
```